# Maclaurin series for $x^6 \cdot e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am being asked to find a Maclaurin series for $x^6 \cdot e^{-x}$ manually for a homework question and am being asked to do it via a table:

http://www.webassign.net/scalcet/11-10-030.gif

I have no idea how to approach this question. I don't want the answer (I need to DIY) but does anyone have any tips on how to actually go about solving this?

Comment: Write up the series of $e^{-x}$ and the series of $x^6$, then multiply the two.

Comment: How do I find the series for x^6?

Comment: Can you find the Maclaurin series of $x$? If yes, find the Maclaurin series of $x^2$. Then do $x^6$.

Comment: What binomial coefficient?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. I know that we use successive derivatives to find the maclaurin series of x. I'm not sure how that translates to finding the maclaurin series of x^6 however. Specifically, how do I represent the maclaurin series of x^6 as the infinite sum of some series from n = 0?

Comment: Please try calculating the series of $x$. Here's the definition, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series. Maclaurin series is the Taylor series at $a=0$, so plug in $0$ in place of $a$ in the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard to build it from other series.  Your table has the series for $e^x$, so it's a simple matter to change all the $x$'s to $-x$'s and you have the series for $e^{-x}$.